# document.getElementById("imgAttach").click(); Access is denied

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, access-denied

I am getting Access is denied in IE

I have a hidden button which i click after another button is clicked:

button clicked calls:

```
document.getElementById("imgAttach").click();
```

And in IE i get an access error. How do i fix this?

The button i'm trying to invoke a click on:

```
<input type="image" name="imgAttach" id="imgAttach" src="ICCMImages/Paperclip.PNG" style="border-width:0px;float:right; visibility:hidden" />
```

Comment: Are you doing any file upload ?

Comment: @Java_User Yes but that code is not reached.

Comment: Check these links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560121/file-upload-using-javascript-returns-access-denied-error-with-stylized-input
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1166